# MVVM in WPF - User Controls

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, user-controls

I have a mainwindow with viewmodel and 2 usercontrols with their own viewmodels. When the app launches usercontrol1 is added to displayviewmodel of mainwindow. In usercontrol1 there is a button to launch usercontrol2 and within usercontrol2 is a button to bring you back to usercontrol1.

I want usercontrol2 to overlay usercontrol1 and when I'm done with usercontrol2 I want it disposed. The displayViewModel is in mainwindow viewmodel and I cant figure out for the life of me how to change displayviewmodel without creating new instances of mainwindow. My initial thought was to route the button commands to maindowviewmodel, but I stumbled on how to do that.. any suggestions?

Comment: "and 2 usercontrols with their own viewmodels" Oh no.  Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel? Does a Grid have a GridViewModel?  Your UserControls should appear and act, from the outside, just like any other UI control.  They shouldn't come with its own data context.  MVVM != no codebehind.  Your UI logic should remain in the codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

> The displayViewModel is in mainwindow viewmodel and I cant figure out for the life of me how to change displayviewmodel without creating new instances of mainwindow.

I am of the belief that usercontrols do not need a VM, only pages. Usercontrols should be self-contained stateless entities with dependency properties which are data passed into the control to do its job.

If one has a main or centralized ViewModel, it should be handling all the data needs and page viewing operations and keep track of the current state of the application. One should subscribe from the VM to the control of User2 and when it signals a change, it is the MainVM to do the actual change.

MVVM is just a fancy way of doing three tiered data systems whose job it is to separate database, from view, from operations. It is not a religion but a **general** guideline. IMHO

---

**Redo** the business and display logic processing by centralizing it into one VM. By avoiding a loose *confederation* of viewmodels and centralizing the operations into one main VM will achieve the goal set forth.

Comment: Agreed. A control class is UI, that's it's only job, and it is self-contained. Nothing to do with viewmodels. It's part of a view.

Comment: It depends. A lot of times in WPF, a UserControl is really acting as a composite of several different, more primitive controls. In that case, the UserControl is more like a "panel" than a "control". For panels, I would say it's entirely appropriate to have a view model. If you are really developing a reusable control, then it makes sense to go the whole nine yards with dependency properties and the like. I do agree that the parent view model should contain the logic to switch out the children, though.

Comment: @devuxer I see your logic in that situation and could agree to that. But I would draw the line on exposing a control's VM in any way shape or form to the outside world.

Comment: @OmegaMan, Not sure what you mean by "outside world" exactly. I regularly hold references to child view models within parent view models so that the view model hierarchy exactly matches the view hierarchy. This has worked very well for many apps I've written. The technique comes from Josh Smith, one of the pioneers of MVVM in WPF (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here can be solved by allowing `MainWindowViewModel` to orchestrate the switching of the `DisplayViewModel`. `MainWindowViewModel` should hold a reference to `UserControl1ViewModel` and `UserControl2ViewModel`. When a request is made to switch to the other UserControl, the view model for the current UserControl should communicate the switch request by publishing an event or message, which MainWindowViewModel subscribes to.

If you use this technique, you can manage the switching of the UserControls within your MainWindow by using a combination of DataTemplates and ContentControl.

To do this, first add these resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControl1ViewModel}">
        <v:UserControl1/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControl2ViewModel}">
        <v:UserControl2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then place a ContentControl where you'd like the UserControl to appear.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding DisplayViewModel}" />
```

As long as your view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, when you set `DisplayViewModel` to a new view model, the UserControls will automatically be switched out.

Comment: I understand the concept of referencing my usercontrols within the mainwindow viewmodel. Its actually setup this way. I guess the part I am struggling with is this... MainWindow initiates and displayviewmodel = usercontrol1. There is a button inside usercontrol1 that will initiate usercontrol2. The block i have is if the command is part of the usercontrol1 view model how do I make reference to the displayviewmodel that is part of mainwindow view model to change the view?

Comment: UserControl1ViewModel should send a message (or fire an event) that is subscribed to by MainWindowViewModel. When MainWindowViewModel responds to the message, it should then set `DisplayViewModel` to UserControl2ViewModel.